# How to fix the order of columns in dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series which I grouped and now I want to save that series as csv file with both index and values as two columns(Index followed by values).

So I first tried to covert the series as dataframe and then save the data frame as csv.

```
s_group_count=df_page_concat.groupby(df_page_concat).count()
df_grouped_values=pd.DataFrame({"page_path":s_group_count.index,"count":s_group_count.values})
```

Problem is since it is using dict to create a dataframe and that dicts are not ordered, it is adding the **count** which is the value of series as the first column in dataframe while I want the Index as first column and values (count) as second column.

Any advise how to fix the order and if this is the most optimal way to create a csv out of series with index stored as another column?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why I would covert the dataframe to dict when I am converting a dict to dataframe and then to csv?

Comment: You can reorder your columns with `df=df[['Col1','Col2','Col3']]` etc

Comment: Why not use `OrderedDict`?

Comment: OrderedDict sa in

Answer (score 0):

`from collections import OrderedDict`

This has been particularly helpful for me in `groupby.agg` operations, to enforce column order

So pass in

```
OrderedDict([("page_path",s_group_count.index),("count",s_group_count.values)])
```